# How can I use RDP (MSTSC.EXE) to log on to server as if you are at the console?

Tags: windows, server, remote-access, desktop, remote-desktop

How can I use RDP (MSTSC.EXE) to log on to server as if you are at the console? I am looking for a way to modify the .RDP so when I execute the remote desktop to a server, the login page is pulled up so i can type my credentials in or use a digipass (vasco) alternative. I also use HP RGS to get into servers and blades, but the version in my environment is buggy and needs to install a client ... but it does accomplish the type of login behavior I am looking for ... when it works. I know that the .rdp file can be modified with a text editor, but I have not had any luck with the settings I have. I am running from a Windows 10 computer.
[Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O85k.png)

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish? The reason I'm asking is that MS added another security layer to RDP and what you want goes counter to this, AFAIK.

Comment: @ Hajo Kirchhoff - Yes. I know this was added after 2003 server. I want to be able to click on the "DigiPass" option on the login screen. I have included a pic of this. This option is not available in the RDP "pop-up" login screen. If there is another way to approach this through RDP, I am certainly willing to learn that as well.

Comment: Ah, I see. RDP includes support for hardware tokens (smartcards), but this does not seem to be an option (or you wouldn't have asked). I don't know if it is possible to dumb down your mstsc.exe and force it to use an older RDP protocol, but you could try to run Linux in a VM (virtual box) and use their RDP client. 3rd party RDP clients usually do not support the latest RDP protocol version and thus the server will fallback to an earlier version. The RDP version you want to use is the one from Windows XP I think. Wikipedia has more info on the different RDP versions. Hope it helps.